# How to monitor all outgoing requests WITHIN app from ALL installed apps?

Tags: java, android, http, traffic

Is it possible to develop an app which can show outgoing requests/connections made from ALL apps within the app **WITHOUT ROOT**?

Other questions I found were about monitoring connections regarding the own app or monitoring outside of Android app such as using some tool on PC which is not what I want. I want to do it from **within my own app** and **for all apps** installed on the android device.

I'm new to Android development so I want to know if it's possible or not.
There are apps in the Play Store such as [Network Connections](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antispycell.connmonitor) which do exactly what I want to do but I cannot find any guides/tutorials/etc. on how to do it.

So is it possible and if yes, what is required to do so?
Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to monitor outgoing requests of all installed applications?

Yes, but with some restrictions.
There are few application available in `Google Play` that provides this service. You can actually check few of them [Debug Proxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dans.apps.webd&hl=en), [Packet Capture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=en).
And these applications don't require `Root Permission`. More over all these applications use a specific kind of attack called **MITM**. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) to learn more about MITM. Also you can get to learn more about this from this [github repository](https://github.com/kasif-dekel/android-mitm-app-no-root)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, there are already existing apps but I want to develop an app myself which does this. Didn't know about MITM (as far as I understood it's for decrypting SSL traffic), gonna check it out. After more googling, in order to get requests/connections, using "netstat" command seems to be the right direction in order to list all outgoing connections as a starting point. Any more input is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

AdGuard has a. Powerful network connections monitoring system. You can use that code to create a stand-alone app